# how to start mintty xorg mode

Tags: cygwin, xorg, mintty

I wonder how I can start mintty in Xorg-mode? (dunno if it called so) Anyway I'm using cygwin, and I execute XWin so I can run emacs in Xorg. However the default shell for XWin is xterm which I wish to change so I can use mintty instead. How to do that?

Comment: For reference, what command are you using to start X (just `XWin`?), and have you made any changes to config files?

Comment: @SamB - i'm using the shortcut created when I installed xorg `D:\cygwin\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe`. The only change I made to the config files is to turn of autostart of xterm when I start xwin.

Answer (score 1):

[Mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) uses the Windows GUI, not X, so you can't run mintty as an X client. You can run mintty windows on the same screen as X applications, though, so you shouldn't have any problem using it instead of xterm on a system running Cygwin.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer to me...

Comment: @SamB: The question was "how I can start mintty in Xorg-mode" and the answer is "you can't". However, there is no reason that starcom can't continue to use mintty alongside X applications on a Windows desktop that's also running an X window manager, which is what starcom appears to really want to do. Running mintty as an X client was what starcom incorrectly assumed he/she had to do to achieve that end. (I'm displaying Windows windows and X windows on my Windows desktop right now.)